# Magento backend and frontend content repeat show

Tags: magento, magento2

I am using Magento 2.2.6, I faced an issue on backend and frontend Magento2 default content and Messages do not show properly in the backend as well frontend. This issue does not appear in installation time. Its Show after once I update Magento Mode production to the developer mode.

Errors: https://prnt.sc/orn3b8

I change much time to Magento mode but it still showed.
 I disabled all extensions and check but it still showed.

Please let me know how I can remove this issue.

Comment: do you change or override any magento core files?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?